# What is the equivalent of domain_get_domain()?

Tags: 8, domain-access

I need the equivalent of `domain_get_domain()` in the Domain Access module for Drupal 8, but I can't find it.

I need to find the domain for the current request.

Answer (score 3):

Finally worked out the following ...

```
$domainNegotiator = \Drupal::service('domain.negotiator');
$current = $domainNegotiator->negotiateActiveHostname();
```

There are other methods on the DomainNegotiator service that I thought should work, particularly `getActiveDomain()` and `getActiveId()`, but they didn't return the domain I was actually on like I thought they would.

It's still a bit confusing to me, but I made it work.

EDIT: 
@berramou 's answer below helped as well. Originally, I was looking for the Domain object (from the Domain Access module), but it turns out the host was enough to match a Domain reference on my entity.

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 8 there is `\Drupal::request()` to get request info.

For Example if your url something like `https://example.com`

If you want only the domain name `example.com`

```
$domain = \Drupal::request()->getHost();
```

if you want the domain name with schema `http or https` `https://example.com` use this:

```
  $domain_with_schema = \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```